# MaxRequestLen error on error_log on file upload attempt

Tags: linux, apache, centos, mod-fcgid, fcgid

I'm using a PHP/MySQL setting on an apache server at Media Temple.

When attempting to upload large files through the customer's admin section (which is pretty common to have 100MB files going up) I get this error:

```
[Thu Aug 16 14:30:38 2012] [warn] [client 64.46.17.53] mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 16785212 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (16777216)
```

In fcgid.conf file I have the following line:

```
FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824600
```

I also tried changing that to

```
MaxRequestLen 1073741824600
```

Anyway teh whole file now looks like this, and when i restart apache there's no errors in configuration.

```
# This is the Apache server configuration file for providing FastCGI support
# via mod_fcgid
#
# Documentation is available at http://fastcgi.coremail.cn/doc.htm

LoadModule fcgid_module modules/mod_fcgid.so

<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>

<IfModule !mod_fastcgi.c>
    AddHandler fcgid-script fcg fcgi fpl
</IfModule>

  FcgidIPCDir /var/run/mod_fcgid/sock
  FcgidProcessTableFile /var/run/mod_fcgid/fcgid_shm

  FcgidIdleTimeout 600
  FcgidMaxRequestLen 1073741824600
  FcgidBusyTimeout 600
  FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
  MaxRequestLen 1073741824600
  FcgidMaxProcesses 20
  FcgidMaxProcessesPerClass 8
  FcgidMinProcessesPerClass 0
  FcgidConnectTimeout 600
  FcgidIOTimeout 600
  FcgidInitialEnv RAILS_ENV production
  FcgidIdleScanInterval 10

</IfModule>
```

What other values do I need to override? I have SSH root access, although very uncomfortable with command-line inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your value is too high. Check [MediaTemple Wiki for that issue](http://wiki.mediatemple.net/w/%28dv%29_4.0%3aResolve_FastCGI_issues#.27HTTP_error.27_When_Uploading_Files), that gives you the config for 1Gb.

Answer (score 0):

Although PHP is outside of scope of support, I can provide you with a (mt) KnowledgeBase article on editing your PHP, http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/137. I hope this will provide you with some help. However, we are always here to answer questions and guide you in the right direction. Please don't hesitate to contact us if you have any further issues. We are available 24/7 via chat, phone and through Twitter. Have a great day!

Kat D.
(mt) Media Temple
Social Media Team